# I have started working with React Native-Js for web app development and am stuck at a point wiith Dispatch function

Tags: reactjs

[image]I am trying to change state of my home page and in that basically changing the movies.

However when I run my dispatch it shows the error as shown in the pic attached.

Aso it is clearly not working properly because the movies array is showing 0 elements.

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ImgSlider from './ImgSlider';
import Viewers from './Viewers';
import Movies from './Movies';
import db from '../firebase';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setMovies } from "../features/movie/movieSlice";

function Home() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   useEffect(() => {
      db.collection("movies").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let tempMovies = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
         console.log(doc.data());
         return { id:doc.id, ...doc.data() }
      })
      dispatch(setMovies(tempMovies));
   });
}, [])
```

**Movies.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import { selectMovies } from "../features/movie/movieSlice";
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    function Movies() {
        const movies = useSelector(selectMovies);
        console.log("This is movies", movies);
        return (
            <Container>
                <h4>Recommender For You</h4>
                <Content>
                    {movies &&
                        movies.map((movie) => (
                            <Wrap>
                                <img src={movie.cardImg} />
                            </Wrap>
    
                        ))
                    }
                </content>
          </container>);
```

**movieSlice.js**

```
        import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
        
        const initialState={
            movies:[ ]
        }
        
        const movieSlice = createSlice({
            name:"movie",
            initialState,
            reducer:{
             SetMovies: (state, action) =>{
                 state.movies= action.payload;
             }
            }
        })
        export const {setMovies} = movieSlice.actions;
        export const selectMovies = (state)=>state.movie.movies;
        export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: hello, @VARUN. I edit yoru problem. Approve that.

Comment: @VARUN JOSHI, there is no pic attached with an error.

Comment: hello, Please click approve button on edit

Comment: First you explain your issus more exactly. So I edit the your question.

Comment: hello, check edit button on your question bottom

Comment: @VARUN On there you can find the edit ,delete and so on button. On edit area, you can find the number 1. on there click edit button and approve the edit

Comment: I have now attached the error message

Comment: The error is shown in the image and i feel that is the reason that in my movies.js file the movies array is not getting updated